# C++ help with error : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float' to 'float [][2]

Tags: c++, arrays, function

and I was doing a program, that isn't so important. Apparently, I cant send parameters to a float function.
the code look something like this

```
float myfunction(float array[1][2])
{
// ...
return 0;
}

int main()
{
float array[1][2];
int foo = 0;
// assigning values to the array

foo = myfunction(array[1][2]);
return 0;
}
```

when I try to compile, I get the error "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float' to 'float [][2]"
What is wrong? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

First, a function prototyped `float myfunction(float array[1][2])` is confusing (**you**), since what it **actually** mean is: `float myfunction(float array[][2])` or `float myfunction(float (*array)[2])`. The function accepts a pointer to (one or more) array(s) of two floats.

Second, the error you get is because the function accepts a pointer to an array, while you're tryinmg to pass it **single** float - element [1][2] of the two-dimensional array `float array[1][2]`. Perhaps you meant to pass the entire array to the function?

Comment: Oh. I'm feeling kinda dumb right now, since I didn't figure that out myself, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Just pass array, without the indexes:

```
foo = myfunction(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the variable: `float array[1][2];` 
Then, you call the function in this way: `foo = myfunction(array);`
As a parameter, only you have to set the variable name. You shouldn't do this: `foo = myfunction(array[1][2]);`

When you make a function, do it in this way: type `myfunction(float Array[][w])` , being type the type of function (void, float...) and "w" a constant integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a certain cell and not the array